# Magnetic antenna for the UV8000E

Tags: connectors

I have the new UV8000E ht and I'm trying to find a magnetic antenna or at least the adapter that allows the unit to be attached  to a pl259 connector.

I have no clue what the connector is other than the fact that it isn't SMA.

Comment: Generally, a link to pictures, a datasheet or any other help at recognizing your connector would … help.

Comment: also, from the product pictures on the website, it sure *does look like* SMA.

Answer (score 1):

According to [KE0OG's video review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxzOt95nc4w) (about 6:36 in), the radio has a male SMA connector, and the antenna has a female SMA connector.  That's the reverse of the Baofeng connectors, which are reverse-SMA.